# What are my five numbers?

Tags: logical-deduction

This nice puzzle was sent to me by a friend. I don't have the original source.

I am thinking of 5 numbers A, B, C, D, E, in that order. Each number is a unique digit between 1 and 9.

- 79314 contains one of my numbers, but in the wrong position.
- 95643 contains two of my numbers, but only one in the right position.
- 57319 contains two of my numbers and both in the right position.
- The sum of the numbers is equal to the last two digits, ie. A+B+C+D+E = 10*D+E.

Can you find the five numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The five numbers are:

> 57628

Explanation:

> Comparing the first and third numbers, we know the answer cannot contain 1 or 3, because these are in the same position in both numbers, but we know that no digit is in correct position in the first number. The 5 in the third number must be correct, and in the correct place, because it is the only digit not appearing in the first number, and we know that the third number has one more correct digit than the first. This, then, means that one of 7 or 9 is correct (in the correct place in the third number, and out of place in the first), because if the 4 in the first number were a correct digit, it would be the only one in that number, and all of 1,3,7,9 would be incorrect in the third number, leaving only one correct digit. So we also know, then, that 4 is not in the answer. In the second number, the 5 must be the out of place digit, as we already concluded a 5 is in the first position. That leaves one more digit in the second number which is in the correct place, so 9 must be wrong, and is not part of the answer (as it is in the spot we know belongs to 5). So 7 is correct in the third number. Comparing the first and second numbers, 6 must be the correct digit in the correct place, as 3 and 4 are not in the answer. This leaves the unused 2 and 8 to finish the puzzle. 5+7+6+2+8 is 28, so the last two numbers are 2 and 8, in that order.

Comment: Well done - that was super fast!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky - We've had a lot of practice with this kind of problem recently!